# Небольшая непонятка со структурами

Tags: структуры, c++

Есть у меня структура, допустим struct ZKN. В ней хранятся чары/инты, не важно.
И захотелось мне сделать 12 таких структур. И тут возник странный глюк (может я просто чего не знаю).
Если после определения структуры сразу написать zkn[11], т.е.

```
struct ZKN
{
...
} zkn[11];
```

то всё работает нормально. Но стоит мне объявить стируктуру, и в **main** написать ZKN zkn[11]; компилятор уже ПОСЛЕ выполнения программы, при том успешного, будет ругаться.
Это он ругается из-за неправильного выделения памяти, или что? И почему тогда сразу после структуры если объявить, то норм, а в main не норм.
Плюс в книге по C++ объявляют что в main, что сразу после структуры - им всё равно. Как так?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В книге правильно написано, что объявлять переменную zkn можно где угодно. Только нужно делать это правильно, если Вам нужно 12 структур, то почему объявляете их 11?

Должно быть:

```
ZKN zkn[12];
```

А ошибка скорее всего связана с выходом за пределы массива, если вы просматриваете 12 элементов массива, в котором их только 11.

Comment: ну так ведь 0-11, не?

Comment: И в таком случае - почему нормально определяет всё, если сразу после структуры написать zkn[11]?

Comment: Все правильно, индекс от 0 до 11, но обявлять массив нужно указав не последний индекс, а кол-во элементов в нем.

Выход за пределы массива - штука не предсказуемая, сейчас все хорошо, через 5 минут нет.